# Sales difference between date and date-1 at product level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to find the difference in sales between the date and date-1 where I have thousands of products

[image]

The O/p I am willing to have is the difference between day 2 to day 1 but at the product level,

Thank you in advance for the help,

Comment: Images of sample data are nearly useless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Are those dates January, February, March? Or all in July? What is the desired output? Maybe you are looking for [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Version of SQL Server? If t is later SQL Server 2012 you can use lag

Comment: Is that the table you are working with? Then self-join, on t1.[date] = t2.[date]-1. If that's not the structure of your table, it will help to provide it.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: How is this question get upvoted twice?  This question shows no research, no attempt. There are tons of solution for this problem on the web.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy . . . SQL Server is a commercial product.  *All* supported versions support `lag()`.  There is no need to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you could use LAG but if you are using an earlier version than 2012 you can self join to the table using the date - 1 day and the product name.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ProductName varchar(1), [Date] Date, Sales int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
('a', '07/01/2019', 5), 
('a', '07/02/2019', 10),
('a', '07/03/2019', 15), 
('a', '07/04/2019', 20),
('b','07/01/2019', 5),
('b','07/02/2019', 10),
('b','07/03/2019', 15),
('b','07/04/2019', 20)

--drop table #TEMP

SELECT 
    a.ProductName, 
    a.[Date], 
    a.Sales,    
    b.[Date],
    b.Sales,
    a.Sales - b.Sales as difference
FROM #TEMP a
LEFT JOIN #TEMP b ON b.[Date] = DATEADD(day, -1, a.[Date]) 
    AND b.ProductName = a.ProductName
```

Output

```
ProductName Date       Sales       Date       Sales       difference
----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
a           2019-07-01 5           NULL       NULL        NULL
a           2019-07-02 10          2019-07-01 5           5
a           2019-07-03 15          2019-07-02 10          5
a           2019-07-04 20          2019-07-03 15          5
b           2019-07-01 5           NULL       NULL        NULL
b           2019-07-02 10          2019-07-01 5           5
b           2019-07-03 15          2019-07-02 10          5
b           2019-07-04 20          2019-07-03 15          5
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic using `lag()` looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (sales -
        (case when lag(date) over (partition by product_name order by date) = dateadd(day, -1, date)
              then lag(sales) over (partition by product_name order by date)
         end)
       ) as diff
from t;
```

Note the logic to handle missing dates for a product.  This also assumes there are no duplicate dates for a product, which is consistent with how the question is phrased.